# Public R Plumber remote

Tags: r, server, remote-access, plumber

According to the documentation, https://www.rplumber.io/, it says that if we use plumber$run() it will just run locally localhost:8000. And I want to publish it in a remote. How can I start a remote API using plumber package?

Answer (score 1):

See the `host` parameter on `run()`. e.g. `$run(host="0.0.0.0")`

Comment: Thanks. Also explained why here: [github plumber #101: Listen on localhost only by default](https://github.com/trestletech/plumber/issues/101)